# How do I draw separate geom_lines in the individual graphs of a faceted ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

For example, the following code:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
geom_point() + 
facet_wrap(vars(class))
```

gives us a set of faceted graphs. How do I add geom_vlines to each individual graph at different points (say at x=2 for compacts and x=5 for 2seaters)?

I tried to add `geom_vline(xintercept = c(2, 5), linetype = "dashed", color = "red")` but that applies to all graphs within the ggplot.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dataset specifically for adding your vlines in, then specify it in the `aes()`.  For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(vars(class)) +
  geom_vline(
    data = data.frame(class = c('2seater', 'compact'), vline = c(5,2)),
    aes(xintercept = vline, group = class)
  )
```

[image]